# Caulking a Large Gap (Shower)

Tags: sealant

Our downstairs shower was due for a re-caulk. Minor mold was happening and cracking. It was time. I proceeded to strip the existing caulking and now I am left with a big gap between the drywall and the shower. Any ideas on how to proceed?

I was also cleaning the fixtures with aluminum and that is was scratched the paint (which I will also be repairing after I figure out the caulking).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*This isn't a job for caulk.*

Flat tape to the tub using setting-type joint compound. Pre-fill the gap first, then set the tape tight to the tub surface (or nearly so). Mask the tub before you begin for easier cleanup later. Use a wide knife and thin applications to achieve flatness. Sand lightly, then prime and paint.

Now you can apply a *tiny* bead of caulk as nature intended and it won't look like the highway department did it for you.

Comment: Looks like a really good way to fix the problem. If someone has the DIY skills to pull it off, that is. If not, a trim strip will be a lot easier and more within a non-house-builder-level skillset.

Comment: Minor drywall repair is a fundamental that shouldn't be avoided because it's a new skill. I don't consider that a barrier.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a reasonable lip between the face of the wall and the face of the shower surround, I would overlay the top of the shower surround with thin PVC strips about a half inch (12mm) wider than the widest gap (give or take), probably available from hardware or big-box stores. This would cover the large gap and allow for more detailed caulking.

Comment: Trim strips are an absolute last resort in almost anything in my opinon. They're easy, but to anyone with a carpenter's or decorator's eye they look lazy and unsightly.

Comment: There is considerable depth as well in the gap.  I'm more concerned with that one area that looks like the drywall has been damaged.

Comment: Good information to be put in your question... Also, there is usually some amount of empty space behind drywall between studs. No need to fill it, just cover it. Unless you think there's water damage behind the drywall, at which point your project is a lot bigger than caulk.